# NSView with gradient background AND shadow

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nsview

I want my NSView to have both gradient background and shadow, so I subclassed `NSView` and overrode the `- (void)awakeFromNib` method like this:

```
[self setWantsLayer:YES]; // view's backing store is using a Core Animation Layer

CAGradientLayer *backgroundGradient = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
backgroundGradient.colors = @[
    (__bridge id)CGColorCreateGenericGray(0.85, 1.0),
    (__bridge id)CGColorCreateGenericGray(0.94, 1.0)
];
backgroundGradient.masksToBounds = NO;

CALayer *shadowLayer = [CALayer layer];
shadowLayer.shadowColor = CGColorCreateGenericGray(0.5, 1.0);
shadowLayer.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(0, 0.0);
shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
shadowLayer.masksToBounds = NO;

[backgroundGradient addSublayer:shadowLayer];

[self setLayer:backgroundGradient];
```

However, only the gradient was shown. In addition, if I try `[self setLayer:shadowLayer]` then the shadow is shown (but of course, no gradient).

How to show both the gradient and the shadow? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the shadow layer supposed to look like?  Surely shadows only work at the edge of a user interface element?  Also why not configure the gradient to have a shadow as well?

Comment: I want it to be like the darker gray box on the front in [Goal image](http://d.pr/i/jzsM)